# UIAutomation not working in background

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to automate a third party windows application. I'm using [UIAutomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is part of .net 3.0 framework.

It works fine when run locally but if I deploy it in a windows server 2003 and make it run scheduled without logging in it does not work. I've done a fair amount of googling and I understand that for security reasons windows may not permit this. Is there a way to achieve this ? Its very similar to doing automated UI testing. How do people do large number of automated UI testing (without opening the server in remote and watching the test cases execute)

My solution is a windows application. (Ideally I would want it to be a web application which automates a manual task on a windows software installed on the server but that seems to be even more of a [challenge](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134))

Desperate ! Will provide more information on request.

Comment: Why are you trying to host the automation on a server?  What you should be doing instead is running it locally against your test environments.

Comment: I'm not the end user! Its basically a manual task that the 'business user' is currently doing which I'm trying to automate !

Comment: Use a testing framework like Coded UI.

Comment: I've already coded using the Microsoft UIA. The issue is only to run it remotely without intervention